# I do accept bitcoins as a way of payment on my website. How could I stabilize value of accepted bitcoins to usd?

Tags: price-volatility, stable-coin

I have a website which accepts bitcoins (and other non-stable coins). The amount of ways to accept coins is pretty big: from btcpay to some proprietary solutions. But I do care about volatility of bitcoin. I could easily accept bitcoins equal to the sum of, saying, 100$. But later on, those could turn to be 20% overnight. Is there any way to stabilize it? The only way I see is to convert btc's to stablecoins, but I believe there are simpler ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedge_(finance)

> A hedge is an investment position intended to offset potential losses or gains that may be incurred by a companion investment. A hedge can be constructed from many types of financial instruments, including stocks, exchange-traded funds, insurance, forward contracts, swaps, options, gambles,[1] many types of over-the-counter and derivative products, and futures contracts.
>
> **Public futures markets** were established in the 19th century[2] to allow transparent, standardized, and efficient hedging of agricultural commodity prices; they have since expanded to **include futures contracts for hedging the values of** energy, precious metals, **foreign currency**, and interest rate fluctuations.

(My emphasis)

---

https://blog.btcpayserver.org/case-study-technical-prism-sideshift/

> When it comes to merchants at events, there's often a common concern:
> **hedging against the wild swings of price volatility**". Even those that
> are game for holding onto Bitcoin earnings, want to ensure that when
> it comes to fixed costs of their vendors, they are covered on every
> sale.
>
> In this guide we will showcase how Prism can be setup so that:
>
> 80% of incoming sats will be converted to stablecoin 10% will be sent
> to another lightning address 10% will stay on the server for demo
> purposes

Comment: Thanks! It's exactly what I was looking for!